# visual studio 2013 Xaml ui designer crash when trying to add event

Tags: wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2013

Everytime I double click an event(to automatically add event template in code behind), xaml ui designer crash. These are the error message.

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(Int32 errorCode)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.CSharp.Services.Language.CodeModel.CCodeFunction.get_Type()
   at EnvDTE.CodeFunction.get_Type()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExpressionHost.Platform.DTECodeContext.CompatibleWith(CodeFunction function, IHostCodeEvent codeEvent)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExpressionHost.Platform.DTECodeContext.<Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.IHostCodeContext.GetCompatibleMethods>d__9.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.RemoteHostCodeContext.<>c__DisplayClass13.<Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.IRemoteHostCodeContext.GetCompatibleMethods>b__12()
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.ThreadMarshaler.<>c__DisplayClass2a`1.<MarshalIn>b__29()
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.Call.InvokeWorker()

System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.

Server stack trace: 
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.WaitForCompletion(NestedCallContext nestedCallContext, BlockingCall call, WaitHandle timeoutSignal)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.MarshalInSynchronous(Action action, Int32 targetApartmentId, CancellationToken cancelToken, CallModality callModality, String methodName, String filePath, Int32 lineNumber)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.MarshalIn(Action action, Int32 targetApartmentId, CancellationToken cancelToken, CallSynchronizationMode syncMode, CallModality callModality, String methodName, String filePath, Int32 lineNumber)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.ThreadMarshaler.MarshalIn(IRemoteObject targetObject, Action action, CallSynchronizationMode syncMode, CallModality callModality, ApartmentState apartmentState, String memberName, String filePath, Int32 lineNumber)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.ThreadMarshaler.MarshalIn[TResult](IRemoteObject targetObject, Func`1 func, CallModality callModality, ApartmentState apartmentState, String memberName, String filePath, Int32 lineNumber)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.RemoteHostCodeContext.Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.IRemoteHostCodeContext.GetCompatibleMethods(String eventName, RemoteHostParameter[] parameters, String returnType)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.IRemoteHostCodeContext.GetCompatibleMethods(String eventName, RemoteHostParameter[] parameters, String returnType)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.LocalHostCodeContext.<>c__DisplayClass16.<Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.IHostCodeContext.GetCompatibleMethods>b__15(IRemoteHostCodeContext cxt)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.ThreadMarshaler.<>c__DisplayClassa`2.<MarshalOut>b__9()
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.Call.InvokeWorker()

System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.WaitForCompletion(NestedCallContext nestedCallContext, BlockingCall call, WaitHandle timeoutSignal)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.MarshalOutSynchronous(Action action, Int32 targetApartmentId, WaitHandle aborted, WaitHandle timeoutSignal, CancellationToken cancelToken, String methodName, String filePath, Int32 lineNumber)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.MarshalOut(Action action, Int32 targetApartmentId, WaitHandle aborted, CancellationToken cancelToken, CallSynchronizationMode syncMode, WaitHandle timeoutSignal, String methodName, String filePath, Int32 lineNumber)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.ThreadMarshaler.MarshalOut[TValue](RemoteHandle`1 targetObject, Action action, CallSynchronizationMode syncMode, ApartmentState apartmentState, String methodName, String filePath, Int32 lineNumber)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.ThreadMarshaler.MarshalOut[TResult,TValue](RemoteHandle`1 targetObject, Func`2 func, CallSynchronizationMode syncMode, ApartmentState apartmentState, String methodName, String filePath, Int32 lineNumber)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.LocalHostCodeContext.Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.IHostCodeContext.GetCompatibleMethods(IHostCodeEvent codeEvent)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignSurface.UserInterface.PropertyInspector.CodeContext.CreateEventHandler(ISourceItemContext item, String typeName, IEvent eventKey, String methodName)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignSurface.UserInterface.PropertyInspector.EventHandlerProvider.CreateEventHandler(IEvent eventKey, String methodName)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignSurface.UserInterface.PropertyInspector.EventHandlerModel.SetMethodName(String newName)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignSurface.UserInterface.PropertyInspector.EventHandlerModel.GenerateAndCommit()
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignSurface.UserInterface.PropertyInspector.EventHandlerModel.<get_GenerateAndCommitCommand>b__1(Object arg)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run()
   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run(Window window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run()
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.DesignerProcess.RunApplication()
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.DesignerProcess.<>c__DisplayClass2.<Main>b__0()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

I tries loading visual studio in SafeMode, unfortunately, xaml ui designer is totally unloadable.

Thanks.